# How to mock ResultSet methods next() and getString() using JMockit?

Tags: java, testing, resultset, jmockit

I am currently using a invocation class to implement my current test requirements however these will get very messy as more conditions need to be added, Does anyone know a better solution with some examples? 
@Rogério

```
@Mock
        boolean next(Invocation in) {

            logger.info("invocation count" + in.getInvocationCount());

            if (in.getInvocationCount() % 2 == 0 && in.getInvocationCount() != 1) {
                logger.info("from resultset" + in.getInvocationCount());
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Database connection is not meant to be mocked. Do not apply unit testing on them, instead use integration testing tools.

Comment: @Rogério Your thoughts please, I cannot connect to the DB as test code is being constructed therefore it must be mocked. This method is working fine as is for the simplier test.

Comment: Consider recording expectations on a `@Mocked ResultSet` instead. I don't know what your test requirements are, so I can't be more specific. Mocking of the JDBC API is always difficult, and best avoided if possible.

Comment: @Rogério My tests require that I have to use methods( next() of resultset ) which is tasked to return different results over the course of one test case, currently I am using invocation class for this purpose. Could you give me an example of how you recommend doing it with the record expections